# Usage of "avert the sound" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I'm describing the usage of carpet. Is the phrase "avert the sound" used correctly?

> A carpet could be used to avert the sound produced by the hard things falling down to floors.

Comment: **<comments removed>** Please try to avoid answering these questions in comments. If you have an answer, please use the 'answer' function. Thanks.

Comment: I've closevoted as Off Topic because I can't see any *specific* point being asked about here - it just looks like proofreading to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *avert* is probably not a good word to use here. It tends to mean "carefully avoid" and kind of implies that it it is difficult to avoid whatever you're averting. For example, you would only "avert" someone's anger if they were especially easily angered. This sounds weird when all you're doing is putting down carpet. There's also a commonly used word for suppressing sound: *muffle*.

Also

> the sound produced by the hard things falling down to floors

is a bit off. This is better:

> the sound of hard things hitting the floor

All together, I'd reword it as

> A carpet could be used to muffle the sound of hard things hitting the floor.

Comment: muffle is a very good word choice for this case.

Answer (score 1):

It does “look good” in the sense of being grammatically and semantically correct, but as noted in StoneyB's comment, it  isn't idiomatic.  The article before “hard things” is particularly obtrusive.  Also, having a carpet reduces sounds of things falling, but doesn't eliminate such sounds completely.

One could write:

> A carpet reduces the noise of things falling on the floor.